# Label appears with delay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My timerLabel appears with 2 seconds delay after all elements are visible.

> @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
>
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>
> ```
>     startTimers()
> }
> ```
>
> func startTimers() {
>
> ```
>     let timerClass = TimerClass()
>     timerClass.startTimer()
>     timerClass.label = { timeLabel in
>         
>         self.timerLabel.text = timeLabel
>     }
>         
>     }
> ```
>
> class TimerClass {
>
> ```
> var startViewController = StartViewController()
> var timer:Timer = Timer()
> var count:Int = 0
> var label: ((String) -> Void)?
> func startTimer() {
>     self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
>     
> }
>
> @objc func timerCounter() {
>     count += 1
>     let time = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: count)
>     let timeString = makeTimeString(hours: time.0, minutes: time.1, seconds: time.2)
>     label?(timeString)
> }
>
> func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
>     return ((seconds / 3600), ((seconds % 3600) / 60), ((seconds % 3600) % 60) )
> }
>
> func makeTimeString(hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) -> String {
>     
>     var timeString = ""
>     timeString += String(format: "%02d", hours)
>     timeString += " : "
>     timeString += String(format: "%02d", minutes)
>     timeString += " : "
>     timeString += String(format: "%02d", seconds)
>     return timeString
> }
>
>  }
> ```

Comment: Unclear what the question is. You start the timer, and after the timer delay, you call `label?(timeString)`. So a delay in the appearance of the text is natural and correct.

Comment: Also I'm a little surprised this works at all, because you are creating and then immediately destroying your TimerClass instance.